# Opening new Activity after clickingg item of listview Recycle view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I found this tutorial on recyclerview with cardview but i am not able to add onitemclick listener to it..i want to click on the items and go to another activity. Please help me. Will be highly appreciated.
Thank you

http://pulse7.net/android/how-to-use-recyclerview-with-cardview-in-android-application/

Comment: Please, provide information (like code snippet) about what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily :

Inside your ViewHolder class :

```
.
.
...
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView cardimage;
        TextView cardtitle;
        Flower Flower;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardimage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardimage);
            cardtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardtitle);
        }
    }
```

Put in constructor, (after super(...) call) :

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new CardOnClickListener());
```

And create this class anywhere you want it

```
class CardOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Handle item click
       Log.e("Clicked !!!");
    }
}
```

I've read before that there is a better way but I like this way is easy and not complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own class with the listeners

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

                if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public static interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

and then on your recycle view:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
       // click
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
      // long click
    }
}));
```

@Abhinav Puri answer is correct, but I wrote this solution in case you want and long click.